# Python subprocess (shell=True), not working for postgres command

Tags: linux, postgresql, subprocess

Using the command line, I **confirm** that the following commands executes correctly

```
echo '\c mydatabase;\i db-reset.sql' | psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

However, in Python, I can **confirm that the following lines do absolutely nothing**, and return an status code of 0.

```
import subprocess

code = subprocess.call(r"echo '\c mydatabase;\i db-reset.sql' | psql -U postgres -h localhost", shell=True)
assert code == 0 # This comes to true
```

Essentially, why is the command invoked using subprocess *not actually doing anything*?

Answer (score 6):

It works, but you need more backslashes.
Also, I would recommend you don't use `shell=True` here.

That is what you do, but without shell:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-h', 'localhost'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(r"\c mydatabase;\i db-reset.sql")
```

Comment: You are right, actually. I just figured this out myself. I needed one extra slash before each one.

Comment: I don't think you need extra backslashes because you are using the r prefix to the string.  But the code sample that Igor gave is good.

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler: No, Brenda, you need extra backslashes, but that is not because of python, but because of shell. Take a look here: http://pastebin.com/N3teJ9zh

Comment: but you have shell=False?  In your dpaste you have shell=True

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler: in my answer with shell=False I have no extra backslashes

Answer (score 2):

Igor has the right approach without a doubt - though it'd be a good idea to close the session afterwards. However, there's a bigger picture issue here, which is that *you should not generally be invoking `psql` to communicate with PostgreSQL from Python*.

Use [the `psycopg2` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/), which is widespread and available almost everywhere, to talk to PostgreSQL directly. This will immensely simplify your database communications.

For cases where you actually need `psql`, like running scripts, please use `psql -f` and a database argument. Your command in this case should be:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call([
        'psql', '-q',
        '-U', 'postgres', 
        '-h', 'localhost',
        '-f', 'db-reset.sql', 
        'mydatabase'
     ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
    print("Failed to invoke psql: {0}".format(ex))
```

... or even better, use `check_output` if you're on a new enough Python version, so you capture error output too. Note the `-q` (quiet mode) flag, too.

(Note that `subprocess` will do its own escaping when you're running on a platform like Windows where there's no sensible `execv` variant system calls or equivalents. So you don't need to care about painful shell escaping quirks.)